# Не удаляются старые изображения в слайдере

Tags: angularjs, slick.js

С сервера, примерно каждые 5 секунд, мне приходят 10 новых изображений. Когда я их оформляю просто в блоке `<div>`, то после прихода новых, старые удаляются и на их месте отображаются новые. Однако когда я подключаю `slick` слайдер, то по приходу новых изображений, старые остаются в слайдере и добавляются новые.

Иначе говоря мне нужно чтобы каждые 5 секунд в моём слайдере были новые 10 изображений. А в данный момент работает так: 10 изображений, прошло 5 секунд, 20 изображений. Еще 5 секунд - 30 изображений и т.д.

Прикрепляю код инициализации `slick` слайдера и [ссылку на GitHub](https://github.com/vasyabigi/angular-slick):

```
<div class="gallery">
                    <slick class="cars-gallery-slider2" init-onload=true data="app.currentItem.item.images" slides-to-show="1" slides-to-scroll="1" arrows="false" fade="true" as-nav-for=".slider-nav2" wait-for-animate="false">
                        <div class="picture" ng-repeat="addr in app.currentItem.item.images" >
                            <a href="http://{{addr}}" class="fancybox" rel="group">
                                <img ng-src="http://{{addr}}">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </slick>
                    <slick class="slider-nav2" init-onload=true data="app.currentItem.item.images" slides-to-show="5" slides-to-scroll="1" arrows="true" as-nav-for=".cars-gallery-slider2" center-mode="true" focus-on-select="true" wait-for-animate="false">
                        <div class="picture" ng-repeat="addr in app.currentItem.item.images">
                            <img ng-src="http://{{addr}}" />
                        </div>
                    </slick>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Как подсказывает [офф. документация](https://github.com/devmark/angular-slick-carousel#slide-data):
необходимо переинициировать карусель каждый раз, чтобы галерея обновлялась на актуальный список картинок.

Вот какой пример там приведён:

**controller:**

```
$scope.number = [{label: 1}, {label: 2}, {label: 3}, {label: 4}, {label: 5}, {label: 6}, {label: 7}, {label: 8}];
$scope.numberLoaded = true;
$scope.numberUpdate = function(){
    $scope.numberLoaded = false; // disable slick

    //number update

    $scope.numberLoaded = true; // enable slick
};
```

**html:**

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="tpl.html">
    <h3>{{ i.label }}</h3>
</script>

<slick ng-if="numberLoaded">
    <div ng-repeat="i in number">
        <div class="" ng-include="'tpl.html'"></div>
    </div>
</slick>
```

---

Есть мнение, что карусель от этого может мигать во время каждой инициации. Решение можно подсмотреть [тут](https://github.com/devmark/angular-slick-carousel/issues/59#issuecomment-201362060): необходимо добавлять директиву

```
var mydir='<my-directive></my-directive>';
var compiled=$compile(mydir)($scope);
$timeout(function(){
      $scope.slickSettings.method.slickAdd(compiled);
})
```

Comment: У меня есть слайдер по нажатию на элемент которого этот элемент должен удалиться. Вот там этот способ рабботает. А в моём вопросе данный метод не работает. Вот такая вот задача)